# Riemann sum not converging

Tags: numerical-methods, riemann-sum, computational-geometry, quadrature

I am trying to find the volume of a hemisphere by numerical integration. I have a set of points equally spaced over x-y plane. I am trying to calculate its volume by trying to evaluate Riemann sum. 
$$V= \sum_i (\Delta x_i)(\Delta y_i)z_i$$

$$V= \sum_i (\Delta a_i)z_i$$

$$V= \frac{\pi R^2}{N} \sum_i z_i $$

where N is the total number of points.

[This is how the points on the sphere look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85CCp.png)

As I evaluate this sum with increasing number of points, the error should go to zero. But I am observing that it is not at all reducing beyond ~21%. [How the error is (not) becoming arbitrarily small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4Fkg.png)

I have used the following python code:

```
R=10 

volume_approx=[]

error=[]

volume_actual=2/3*np.pi*(R**3)

pts_range=range(10,10000)

for i in pts_range:

    pts = create_uniform_hemisphere(i, R) #(this creates a uniform hemisphere with i points and radius=R)

    base_area=np.pi*(R**2)

    volume=(base_area/i)*np.sum(pts[:,2])

    volume_approx.append(volume)

    err=(volume_actual-volume)/volume_actual

    error.append(100*err)
```

Can anyone tell me what mistake I am making? Similar behavior is repeated when I try to find volume of a cone, or use randomly spaced points. But this behavior is NOT repeated when I try to calculate volume of a cylinder or a paraboloid with similar code.

Edit: I have used the following code to create the hemisphere:

```
def create_uniform_hemisphere(n, radius):
    step=2*radius/(math.floor(math.sqrt(n)))
    X,Y = np.mgrid[-radius:radius:step, -radius:radius:step] #create mesh on x-y plane

    X=X.flatten()
    Y=Y.flatten()

    X=np.reshape(X,(X.shape[0],1))
    Y=np.reshape(Y,(Y.shape[0],1))
    pts=np.append(X,Y,axis=1)

    pts=pts[(X.flatten()**2 + Y.flatten()**2)<radius**2] #filter points out of circle

    Z=(radius**2-(pts[:,0]**2 + pts[:,1]**2))**0.5 #project onto hemisphere
    Z=np.reshape(Z,(Z.shape[0],1))

    pts=np.append(pts,Z, axis=1)

    return pts
```

Comment: Welcome to MathStackExchange! Please avoid posting images for equations, type them for a better overall experience for everyone in this site (see [mathjax help](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)). Also, consider integrating the appropriate volume element in [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system)

Comment: You don't mention how you create the uniform grid, which is kind of the most important thing here.

Comment: It's impossible to tell what the problem is without knowing exactly what create_uniform_hemisphere(i, R) does. The description "(this creates a uniform hemisphere with i points and radius=R)" really tells us nothing, since we have no idea for example what a "uniform hemisphere" is. Also we have no evidence that the function actually _does_ that, whatever it means.

Comment: A very simple way to create a regular grid is to make the points $x = \{-R + 2*R*i/n\}_{i=1}^n$, $y = \{-R + 2*R*i/n\}_{i=1}^n$ and add all pairs of points for which $x^2+y^2 \leq R^2$. The grid spacing will then be $\Delta x = \Delta y = \frac{2R}{n}$ and you will add up $\sqrt{R^2 - x^2 - y^2} (2R/n)^2$ over the points you added. This should give very good results even for $n = 50$ (which will give you a total of $(\pi/4) n^2 \sim 2000$ points).

Comment: I have made some edits and additions that you guys have suggested. I don't think the problem is in how I am creating the hemisphere (I guess). The problem persists even if I use random spacing. The problem mysteriously disappears for some other shapes (like cylinder or paraboloid) even with random spacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you posted (images and code) it seems you are doing roughly the right thing. The big unknown is the function "create_uniform_hemisphere(i, R)".

You are assuming in your code and the formula (by simply adding the $z$-values of your hemisphere and scaling the sum with $\frac{base\_area}i$) that each point of your sample is representing the same area ($\frac{base\_area}i$) in the projection to the $xy$-plane.

My guess is that this is not true!

It's easy to put 9, 16 (or any square number of) points into a square and have each point  represend the same area of the base. It's much harder to do that with 17 points. Now try to do that for a circle!

My suggestion: Make a 2D plot that plots the points (x=pts[0],y=pts[1], z=0) in the $xy$-plane, similiar to the 3d plot that you posted. Look at this plot directly from above ($z$-direction). Do that for for a few small $i$ (try 20, 25, 30) and see if there are actually 20/25/30 points in the circle (and not just that many points in the square that encompasses the circle).

Next, do it for a big $i$, like 100,000. Try to confirm visually that the points are roughly equally dense in each area. It suspect that they may not be, maybe more dense in the center or something similar.

ADDED: I can't really understand the added code at the moment, but the most obvious potential problem case is that I assume that the length of the returned array pts is smaller than the $i$ you use in the main problem. I assume that from the way you create the array. Please add a check in your main loop to compare $i$ and the lenght of the array pts!

If I'm correct, this would also account for the value of your difference ($21\%)$.

Because if you have exactly $i$ points in the bounding square, you have $\frac{\pi}4i$ points in the circle. $1-\frac{\pi}4=0,2146\ldots.$

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally found the root of the error and corrected it. The problem was that I was starting with some number of points, then discarding some of them, and only using the remaining for projection. I had not updated this fact in my code! I was banging my head on this from 3 days! Thank you very much!

Edit: Yes, you pointed out the exact error in your edit while I was typing my comment. :D